# How to map globally declared modules to the project in angular2?

Tags: angular, node-modules

I have installed series of packages globally, for instance

@angular/core

@angular/Http

> in the folder C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

But i am not able to map all the global package in my systemjs.config.js file, how can i do that? the following is my **systemjs.config.js** file

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

I tried changing

```
paths: {
          // paths serve as alias
          'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        }
```

to

```
 paths: {
              // paths serve as alias
              'npm:': C:/Users/lijin662330/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/'
            }
```

still i am getting an error stating @angular/core not found

Comment: i have package.json in my parent folder and node_modules folder in the global location

Comment: yes, could you answer my question please

Comment: first understand my question, i have setup my project, i have installed my package globally, so i just want to know, how to map a globally installed library

Comment: what is the use of this command then, npm install -g @angular/core? this will install the package in this C:/Users/lijin662330/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/ folder path, right?

Comment: dont comment when you dont know the answer